# Sourcetree Push Succeeds Despite Massive Error Message

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm getting a massive Sourcetree error message every time I push to a remote branch. This didn't happen to me before, and started around 3 days ago for no apparent reason. The interesting part is that the push works.

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks commit -q -F C:\Users\REMOVED\AppData\Local\Temp\34seauwt.ngj

git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks push -v --tags --set-upstream origin REMOVED/Sourcetree-Debug-Error-Messages:REMOVED/Sourcetree-Debug-Error-Messages
Pushing to gitlab.ad.REMOVED.com:dev/REMOVED.git
remote: 
remote: To create a merge request for REMOVED/Sourcetree-Debug-Error-Messages, visit:        
remote:   https://gitlab.ad.REMOVED.com/dev/REMOVED/-/merge_requests/new?merge_request%5Bsource_branch%5D=REMOVED%2FSourcetree-Debug-Error-Messages        
remote: 


To gitlab.ad.REMOVED.com:dev/REMOVED.git
 = [up to date]          REMOVEDTAG-20200810a -> REMOVEDTAG-20200810a
 = [up to date]          REMOVEDTAG-20200819a -> REMOVEDTAG-20200819a
 = [up to date]          REMOVEDTAG -> REMOVEDTAG
```

This gets quite annoying since it happens every time I push to remote (not every time I commit).

I'm using Sourcetree verions 3.3.9 and push using SSH.

Comment: That's not an error message, it's just informational. How you get them not to tell you this information (if that's possible at all), I have no idea, though.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Commit Options and select Bypass commit hooks. It worked for me.

Comment: Can you expalin why that worked?

Answer (score -1):

Whatever text you see after the keyword `remote:`  is sent by the remote git server. It's not an error, it's just the message that git server sends to you during the push process. This is usually done by the server admin in order to inform users of something important/useful, so it's a good idea to read it and, if needed, act accordingly.

The lines starting with `=` show the activities that happened since you last synced your local repository with the remote repository. Those are usually changes done by other developers and those are not errors, obviously.

On the other hand, it might be useful to you to learn to use git from the command line, instead of using UI wrappers, like SourceTree, TortoiseGit and similar, because all those wrappers sooner or later introduce some bugs, increasing the number of points of failures. Also, if you learn how to use git from the command line, you'll be able to work across multiple operating systems, even those that don't have a GUI (like linux server variants). It's convenient to use wrappers in the beginning, until you learn some basics, but later on you'll probably want to have more control, so you'll start doing things from the command line, manually.